# How to use "know" and "realize" correctly

Tags: differences, verbs

Are they just actually the same? Especially as in the following examples:

> I realize then whom I love.
>   I know then whom I love.

Answer (score 13):

*To know* something describes a steady state. *To realize* something is to transition from a condition of ignorance into knowledge. If you put it into a timeline, when you *realize* something you change from *not knowing* to *knowing*:

```
<--- I don't know X ---| I realize X |--- I know X --->
```

*To realize* contains the additional connotation that your knowledge is gained by introspection, contemplation, or a change in self-awareness. If someone merely *tells* you something, you wouldn't say *I realized X.* You would say instead *I learned X* or something similar. When you *realize* something, you assert that you've come to that knowledge under your own power.

Comment: 'Know' _is_ also used inchoatively, perhaps even punctively. 'At that moment, I know for the first time / I know the meaning of life / ....' But 'realise' _is_ inchoative (in the semantic sense, _relating to a beginning_).

Answer (score 4):

If you *realize* that you're in love, then you have just had a revelation about where your feelings lie. One of the [definitions](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/realize) of *realize* is:

> to grasp or understand clearly.

To *know* something is more long-term, perhaps after having realized it. The [first definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/know) for *know* is:

> to perceive or understand as fact or truth; to apprehend clearly and with certainty

They sound similar, but in usage to *realize* something is more of an "aha!" moment, while knowing something can last far longer than that. It may take you a while to come to a realization, but you will not actively realize something for a long period of time.